# run button working, when website will be load

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want with Javascript after website load, automatic run one button click (so run button)

[this is button information and i want this button run when website will be load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVXSm.png)

Comment: Call the event handler function on page load. Check `DOMContentLoaded` and `window.onload`.

Comment: I want a girl with a short skirt and a long jacket - if you can't copy/paste 5 lines of html into a question, I can't be bothered clicking on an image of code

Comment: i dont know so javascript that i get it, i dont know what is DOMContentLoaded or window.onload

Comment: this is code:  { <div class="author_likedin">
                                                                    <div><button id="liked" class="likebuttonliked" onclick="timeInfo()">მოწონებულია</button></div>
                                                                        <div id="likedInfo"><p id="ptag"></p></div>
                            </div> }

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the code there. See [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: help me anyone )

Comment: @KidsTV If you don’t know JavaScript, maybe you should learn it. You should also make clear what you are trying to do, what code you _do_ have, and what is not working yet. If you’re just going to copy and paste code from elsewhere and ask everybody else to work out what’s wrong with it, you won’t get a lot of help.

Comment: here are strange people: i already written top, what is my problem.

Comment: Just writing your problem is not enough, you also need to post your source code not images to it.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao check pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjwJLZ
i want run hat function automatical

Comment: You still need to edit your question, and add the code to it. Make a snippet and then describe your problem.

Comment: strange :D why are saying so, you said already everything without how to do that what i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
window.onload = timeInfo("automatically on load,");

function timeInfo(message) {
  console.log(message + " called function");
}

document.getElementById("liked").addEventListener("click", function() {
  timeInfo("clicking button");
});
```

```html
<div class="author_other_button">
  <button id="liked" class="likebuttonliked">მოწონებულია</button>

</div>
```

Comment: thnx that it ; .................